# Distance between point and plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Find the distance from the Point $A = (1,0,2)$ to the plane passing through the point $(1,-2,1)$ and perpendicular to the line given by the parametric equations:

$$
\begin{align}
x & = 7, \\ 
y & = 1 + 2t, \\
z & = -3 + t.
\end{align}
$$

The answer is $\sqrt{5}$, but I can't seem to get that. I get that the plane equation ends up being $0x + 2y + z + 3 = 0$, but then when I try to compute the distance it turns out to be $\sqrt{3}/\sqrt{5}$ or something along those lines.

Comment: The plane is correct, can you show your working for the distance?

Comment: Ok, so then I try to use the equation |PQ dot n|/||n||.     P(1,-2,1) Q(1,0,2) so PQ = <0, -2, 1>. When I multiply n and PQ together it gives me 3 instead of 5.

Comment: Is it because I should use the given point as P instead of Q?

Comment: Better calculate $PQ$ again... carefully... ;-)

Comment: See, so my question is how do you know which one to pick as P and which one to pick as Q?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  You might end up with a negative distance but then you just take the absolute value.  $P$ and $Q$ as you have them are fine, but $PQ={}$...?

Comment: PQ for me to get the correct answer should be <0,-2,-1>, but I get the wrong answer when I do PQ and subtract the other way.

Comment: No way!  Since $PQ=(0,-2,-1)$, you will have $QP=(0,2,1)$, they will both give the same answer except that one of them will be negative.

Comment: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html).

Answer (score 1):

We will utilize the point-plane distance formula [[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html)].
$$D=\frac{\left\lvert ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d \right\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
We already know that the point in question is $A(1,0,2)$ which means $x_0=1$, $y_0=0$, and $z_0=2$.
$$D=\frac{\left\lvert a(1)+b(0)+c(2)+d \right\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{\left\lvert a+2c+d \right\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
Since the plane in question is orthogonal to the given line, we can find a normal vector to the plane that is contained in the line. The line contains the points $P(7,1,-3)$ and $Q(7,3,-2)$ when $t=0$ and $t=1$, respectively. The vector from $P$ to $Q$ can be found easily. It is orthogonal to the plane.
$$\vec{\mathbf{n}}=\langle(7-7),(3-1),(-2+3)\rangle=\langle0,2,1\rangle$$
We can place the components of this vector into the general equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ [[2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)].
$$0x+2y+1z+d=0\implies2y+z+d=0$$
This plane contains the point $(1,-2,1)$. We can solve for the constant $d$.
$$2(-2)+(1)+d=0\implies-3+d=0\implies d=3$$
We can now return to the distance formula and finish solving the problem with $a=0$, $b=2$, $c=1$, and $d=3$.
$$D=\frac{\left\lvert a+2c+d \right\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{\left\lvert (0)+2(1)+(3)\right\rvert}{\sqrt{(0)^2+(2)^2+(1)^2}}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{5}=\sqrt{5}$$